# Can I use Unity with XMonad?

Tags: unity, window-manager, xmonad

I've been using Fedora for a while, but I recently decided to upgrade my ubuntu installation from 12.04 to 12.10. While I was using Fedora, I found xmonad tiling window manager which I sort of got working with xfce. I really like xmonad and I now automatically use the keyboard shortcuts without even thinking.

So I would like to use xmonad with unity. Now, I have seen several blog posts etc. that explain how to setup the whole thing in 12.04, with Unity2D. But now, Unity2D has been removed, and the old methods no longer apply. I have read that Unity is actually just a Compiz plugin, and that the wm can't be replaced. Does no version of Unity have a replaceable WM?

I've also tried MATE (GNOME2 fork) with xmonad on 12.10 and that is totally broken for me, but that's for another question.

Comment: You can change the window manager. I've used Emerald in 12.10 successfully. But I didn't try xmonad. To change it use ccsm and edit the Window Decorator

Comment: @ÁngelAraya isn't emerald just a window _decorator_? I looked in ccsm but there is no option to change the window manager (I think compiz is the wm)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible, Unity needs Compiz as it's a plugin, sorry!