# Are there any tiling window managers compatible with Unity3D?

Tags: unity, window-manager, xmonad

I used to run Xmonad with Unity 2D which I really love, but since Ubuntu 12.10 the Unity 2D is no more.

Are there any other tiling window managers that runs well with Unity (3D)?

**EDIT:**
I fell back to use Gnome panel and Xmonad. The pre-configured gnome-panel isn't as bad as it was a few releases ago. Although I still miss the global menu bar.

Comment: I'm looking for one too. I'll try to use awesome, but I don't know if it works.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/207195/can-i-use-unity-with-xmonad

Comment: The point for me is that I want to use HUD together with a good tiling window manager

Answer (score 10):

It's not exactly what you wanted, but there is support for some tiling-like features in Compiz:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> on the number pad will put a window onto the bottom-left corner, and the rest of the numbers will put windows to other corners.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> will put the window on the left side of the screen, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> will put it on the right.

I hope that'll be of some use to you.

Comment: Thanks, but that is pretty much only useful when having one single monitor. I've got four.

Comment: Also have a look at "Put To Next Output" (part of the Put plugin), which moves the window to the next monitor.